# nginx ssl ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting an error on the SSL, my site is

https://pontebuso.com/

But it always give me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

*sudo netstat -anp |grep :443| grep LISTEN*

```
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:443      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      1165/nginx 
tcp6   0   0 :::443               :::*           LISTEN      1165/nginx
```

*sudo netstat --numeric -l -p -A ip | grep tcp*

```
tcp        0  0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1130/sshd       
tcp        0  0 0.0.0.0:443         0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1165/nginx      
tcp        0  0 127.0.0.1:9000      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1241/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0  0 0.0.0.0:3306        0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1214/mysqld     
tcp        0  0 0.0.0.0:80          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1165/nginx
```

*root@05A:~# sudo ufw status verbose*

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From

--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
23.253.246.119 443/tcp     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

-------------------nginx.conf---------------------------

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    autoindex off;

    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    #include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request "'
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    keepalive_timeout  10;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

-------------------default---------------------------

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name pontebuso.com;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin sub.pontebuso.com;
        root /home/sites/pontebuso/;

        autoindex off;

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
            access_log off;
            expires max; 
        }

        ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
        location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

        location /var/export/ {
            auth_basic           "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
            autoindex            on;
        }

        location  /. {
            return 404;
        }

        location @handler {
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires        off;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ .php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
         }


         location ~ .php$ { 
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }


    }
```

-------------------pontebuso.conf---------------------------

```
#server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name localhost;
#    rewrite ^/(.*) https://pontebuso.com/$1 permanent;
#    }

server {
       listen 443 ssl;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/pontebuso.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/pontebuso.key;   

        server_name pontebuso.com;

        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
        fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin sub.pontebuso.com;
        root /home/sites/pontebuso/;

        autoindex off;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
            access_log off;
            expires max; 
        }


        ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
        location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }


        location /var/export/ {
            auth_basic           "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
            autoindex            on;
        }

        location  /. {
            return 404;
        }

        location @handler {
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires        off;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ .php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
         }


         location ~ .php$ { 
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }


    }
```

Comment: what webserver are your running? can you post the configuration of it, possibly there is a configuration problem with the ssl part. Hint: the ufw rule `23.253.246.119 443/tcp     ALLOW IN    Anywhere` is overridden by the rule `443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere`.

Comment: Web server   nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: okay. can you post the configuration for your site causing the ssl connection and if possible a logfile output from nginx showing the error happening?

Comment: Thats the strange thing, there's no log file
And my site is Magento

I can send you the file to mail

Comment: okay so then we need to look at your configuration. can you add nginx configuration for your site to the question above (edit and add the infos)? without configuration or log files I can't help you.

Comment: Ready files uploaded

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting this as not the final answer, but a work-in-progress answer. I modified your configuration file `pontebuso.conf` but it might not yet work. I've commented out some parts of it as I consider them as not necessary for a first working solution. They might be added later on, when the basic configuration works. I assume you are running a wordpress blog? Additionally your configuration shows that nginx is writing error logs to `error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;`. For additional help the content is really important. If the files are empty then theres possibly another misconfiguration issue.

edit: removed the config part. Didn't know it's supposed to server a magento store. please review https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/creating-a-faster-magento-store-part-one-server-setup/ and leave out the varnish part. check your nginx config and compare it with the one the site suggests.

Comment: No, i add the file and restar /etc/init.d/nginx restart but im goting the same error

https://pontebuso.com/

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

It's a Magento Store

Comment: edited my answer.